# Firebase Database REST get with orderBy value and parameters

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> database.rules.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    "meetings" : {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
      ".indexOn" : ["date"]
    }
  }
}
```

> Request URL

```
"https://{baseURL}/meetings.json?orderBy=date&equalTo=20181005"
```

> Error Message
>   error: "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"

But

```
"https://{baseURL}/meetings.json"
```

No Error.
What did I do wrong? Plz help me.

Comment: Have you tried `https://{baseURL}/meetings?orderBy=date&equalTo=20181005`. It sounds like the error message is saying `orderBy` isn't a valid url for JSON.

Answer (score 14):

The value of the `name` parameter in your URL needs to be enclosed in `"` quotes. So:

```
https://{baseURL}/meetings.json?orderBy="date"&equalTo=20181005
```

Depending on the way you store the values of the `date` property, the value of the `equalTo` parameter may also need be enclosed in `"` quotes. If you store `date` as a string, it needs to be:

```
https://{baseURL}/meetings.json?orderBy="date"&equalTo="20181005"
```

For more on this, read the [Firebase documentation on querying using the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-a-specified-child-key).

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the exact issue.. and the trick is..the passing value should be "string " encode,

as example below..

```
searchRecordById(recordId: string) {
    return this.http.get(
      `https://your-app.firebaseio.com/skdocs.json`,
      {
        params: {
          **orderBy: '"folder"',
          equalTo: '"Panchla-2"',**
        },
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape the quotes for it to work. E.g.

```
"https://{baseURL}/meetings.json?orderBy=\"date\"&equalTo=\"20181005\""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using curl then try this:

```
curl 'https://{baseURL}/meetings.json?orderBy="date"&equalTo=20181005'
```

If you fetch url from web or etc then url should be :

```
https://{baseURL}/meetings.json?orderBy="date"&equalTo=20181005
```